# Node.js and socket.on data

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i have problem with data and socket.io in node.js. It's possible to get data outside socket.on function? Example:

```
var newdata=new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){


socket.on('Select', function(data){


    //console.log(data.products[0][1]);
    for(i=0; i<data.products[0].length; i++)
    {
        newdata.push(data.products[0][i]);

    }
       console.log(newdata); //array with objects
});


console.log(newdata); //undefined - here i want to get data
```

Comment: Yea it is possible, declare a global outside variable and reassign the variable with the data for use outside or pass it in a method to use in another function. The 'on' method is a event listener that calls during runtime. So you need a callback to a function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a callback function in this case, because `socket.on` is being called asynchronously.

For example, declare a function like this:

```
function processData(newdata) {
  console.log(newdata);
}
```

Then inside your `socket.on('Select', function (data) { ... });` you can call `processData(newdata)`, like below:

```
function processData(newdata) {
  console.log(newdata);
}

$(document).ready(function(){


    socket.on('Select', function(data){

        for(i=0; i<data.products[0].length; i++)
        {
            newdata.push(data.products[0][i]);
        }

        processData(newdata);
    });
});
```

Comment: isn't this the same as console.logging it in the socket.on() callback? wouldnt declaring a global variable be better?

Comment: Absolutely, but I guess he wants to handle it outside of this function, for some reasons.